# How to fix unusual error while compiling c program on linux mint?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-platform

I have written a C program. It compiles and works fine on DevC on Windows 7.
But when I compile it on Linux mint (using 'gcc main.c' command) it does not compile and give errors. These errors are not shown while compiling on Windows 7. So nothing must be wrong on Linux as well! How to compile it on Linux through `gcc`?

C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char command[100];

   printf("Enter the command:");
   scanf("%[^\t\n]", &command);
   printf("%s\n", command);
   strchr(command, '&');

   printf("%i", strchr(command, '&'));

   system("PAUSE"); 

   return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
mint@mint ~ $ gcc ass1/main.c
ass1/main.c: In function 'main':
ass1/main.c:8:5: warning: format '%[^   
' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[100]' [-Wformat]
ass1/main.c:11:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strchr' [enabled by default]
ass1/main.c:13:5: warning: format '%i' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Wformat]
```

Comment: `scanf("%[^\t\n]", &command);` -- this is wrong.  For a char array using %s you would simply pass `command` as the param.  That's the warning on line 8.  Line 13 is complaining that strchr returns a char, but you're formatting it as an int. Use %c.

Comment: Also, strchr is defined in <string.h> on many platforms.  You should #include that to get rid of the implicit declaration warning.

Comment: Lastly: system("PAUSE"); won't work on Linux, there's no PAUSE command.  But you shouldn't need this anyway.

Comment: strchr is also included in string.h, that you don't include. Another thing: I don't think that system("PAUSE") works in linux. You can wait for an input using getchar for example.

Comment: The strchr problem is solved. 
And I used the same piece of code on windows. 
It compiled without errors and gave the correct results.

Comment: Dev-C++ is a crappy compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't errors, they're warnings. Your code should have still compiled.

The first warnings is because you're passing `&command` to `scanf`, which is of type `char (*)[100]`, and the specifier `%s` expects an argument of type `char *`. All you simply need to do is pass `command` to `scanf` (without the `&`), since a `char` array will decay into a `char*` when passed to a function.

You'll probably find that the code still works, with `command` and `&command` both referring to the same address (`printf("%p %p", command, &command);`).

The second warning is due to you forgetting to include `<string.h>`, which declares `strchr`. Since the compiler can't find the declaration, it implicitly generates one, which doesn't turn out to match the real one.

Lastly, `strchr` returns a `char*`, and the specifier `%i` is intended to be used for `int`s. If you want to print out an address using `printf`, use the `%p` specifier.

You should also probably avoid `system("PAUSE");` (which won't work on Linux), and replace it with a function that waits for user input.

Answer (score 3):

> These errors are not shown while compiling on windows 7. So nothing must be wrong on linux as well!

That's a wrong conclusion. In this case, the compiler on Windows is far more lenient than gcc.

gcc warns you about your mistakes/errors, in

```
scanf("%[^\t\n]", &command);
```

you pass the address of `command` where you should pass the address of the first byte in `command`, either as `command` with the automatic array-to-pointer conversion, or explicitly as `&command[0]`.

You use `strchr` without declaring it, an error in non-ancient versions of C, but allowed previously, where a use implicitly declared a function as returning an `int`. `strchr` however, returns a `char*`.

And in your `printf` call, you use the wrong format, `%i`.

gcc is completely correct here.

Note that those are *warnings*, and (unfortunately) not *errors*.

Comment: If you want to print the pointer value, `printf("%p\n", (void*)strchr(command, '&));` is the correct way. But it may be possible that your Windows compiler doesn't know that format (it's C99, as far as I remember), then casting the pointer to an integer type may be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating the previous answers, the code that will compile on Linux and will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> // use this header to include strchr(command, '&');

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char command[100];

   printf("Enter the command:");
   scanf("%s", command);
   printf("%s\n", command);
   strchr(command, '&');

   printf("%p", strchr(command, '&')); 
   /* strchr(command, '&') returns a pointer so you need to tell printf you are printing one. */

   system("PAUSE"); 

   return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
oz@Linux:~$ gcc -Wall test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:12:4: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
oz@Linux:~$ ./a.out 
Enter the command:doSomething
doSomething
sh: 1: PAUSE: not found
```

Instead of

```
  system("PAUSE");
```

use:
   printf("Press 'Enter' to continue: ...");
   while ( getchar() != '\n') {
      i=1;
   }
   getchar();
   return 0;

Comment: Pay attention at the last line of the output. It is warning you that it's trying to execute the PAUSE command.

Comment: @Simone-Cu: `alias PAUSE=true` ;)

Comment: @Simone-Cu, that is how the OP typed the program, it's because the Prompt in windows always closes after the program ends.

Comment: @Oz123 I know that, but I think it's better to avoid it on linux. And what about a solution with `getchar(); getchar();`? Is there a better way to manage waiting for <enter key> that's "cross-platform"?

Comment: @Simone-Cu, I have no clue, I am not the best C programmer, still learning this weired language :-(